# Which parts of an address should be required?

Tags: sql, street-address

Say I am storing addresses in a DB table, in this fairly common break down:

```
address_street_line_1,
address_street_line_2,
address_city,
address_state,
address_zip,
address_country_id
```

(Note: I have read the questions on splitting down further, street type, house number, etc. and for this application I think it would unnecessarily complicate things.)

To work best with international users, which of these fields should NOT be required?

I'm thinking this:

```
address_street_line_1 REQUIRED
address_city REQUIRED
address_country_id REQUIRED
```

Should I require state or zip?

Thanks!
Xavier

Comment: What are you going to do with the addresses?  That's very pertinent information that you have so far left out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all countries even use postal codes, for example they were rarely used in New Zealand prior to 2006 or so. I think Ireland doesn't use them at all.

If you're truly international, city-states such as Singapore don't actually need a City field.

In the user interface, you can (and perhaps should) make the postcode required for countries where you already know it's required, since that isn't likely to change. And, if you make the UI dynamic enough, you can call it "Zip code" if the selected country is the United States, "Postal code" for Canada, "Postcode" for the UK, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this info.  I was unsure about zip/postcode being used everywhere.  I will leave it optional.

Comment: Re: the city-states.  With state being optional, couldn't they just put "Singapore" in the city field?  Or is this weird for them?  Do you think CHECK(city IS NOT NULL OR state IS NOT NULL) is best?

Comment: I suspect in reality, putting "Singapore" in both City and Country fields is something they would probably do anyway. Besides, presumably Country will be required so it will get there in any case.

Comment: I'm giving you +1 for considering Canada

Answer (score 6):

You can probably only require one field: country.

But what you should really be doing is making the logic dependent on country. Take a look at [Address Formats by Country](http://www.addressdoctor.com/en/countries_data/addressformats.asp) for a comprehensive list. That isn't just about required fields either. It's also about correct formatting. A US address might be:

8031 Main Street
Springfield OH 12345
USA

whereas in Switzerland:

Bodenstr. 173
8043 Zürich
Schweiz

**Note:** the street numbers and post codes are in the "reverse" order for Switzerland (compared to what English speaking countries use).

Also, your data types need to be broad enough to cover data used in other countries. Zip/post code should absolutely **not** be a numeric type. For example, "EC2R 8AH" is a valid UK postcode.

That goes back to this principle: if you don't perform arithmetic on it, it's not a numeric type. It's text.

Also, try not to call it Zip Code to end users. That's a US only term. Pretty much everywhere else its call a Postcode, Post code or Postal Code. Also note that the UK postal codes are alphanumeric and include a space.

Comment: Do you have a formatting problem there? The address appears empty.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on postcode naming.  I will leave it optional though given Greg Hewgill's comment below.

Comment: +1 for "if you don't perform arithmetic on it, it's not a numeric type".

Answer (score 1):

I would say everything except street_line_2  and state- and think of 'zip' as more of a [postal codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code) instead of zip code - as you can tell from the variety of format based on the country of origin, this should have a pretty open format.

Answer (score 1):

How about making none required? If the user wants to be contacted they'll enter enough information. Or, enter a single text field and let them enter free form information. They know better than you what fields are required for postal deliveries to make it to their door.

Comment: It's not for postal deliveries.  And I would like some degree of breakdown for reporting.  This seems a pretty common format across the web.  I think none required is a bit extreme, for a start some kind of street address (or landmark name) and a country is going to be in every address is it not?

Comment: +1 because this idea should be considered for some apps. Unless the end user has a personal incentive to supply a correct address, don't be surprised when your db fills up with garbage addresses entered by people who didn't want to share their info. Merely making a field 'required' does not magically force people to enter correct data. They'll enter a space character, a period, etc. I do it all the time on reg forms, I'll bet you have too.

Answer (score 1):

Even in the U.S., most of the address is not required.  A large fraction of U.S. zip codes are allocated to various businesses and organizations - any mail to one of those zips will be delivered the same regardless of the rest of the address.  For instance:

General Electric
Schenectady, NY 12345

Internal Revenue Service
Ogden, UT 84201-0027

The city and state are nice, but the mail will probably get delivered without.

Comment: Interesting to know, thanks.  It's like that in the UK too.  However this is not for postage.

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I have found to solve this problem is by abstracting the logic in your application layer, and not the persistence layer. One of the cleanest/simplest ways I've seen this done is by passing the user's data in a value object (creating a common interface that's easy to validate against) to a validator with the current country code, which makes sure all the required attributes are set properly in the value object for that locale. Assuming it passes validation, pass the value object along to the persistence side of your application for storage.

The key here is the value object - you're creating a common interface that multiple pieces of your application can talk to, validate, and read/write from. You can then also use that same value object when displaying the address: have your persistence layer get the information, put it in the value object, pass it to a factory with the current locale which returns the desired address format, and send that output to the front end.

Comment: Hey I like this idea.  Can you recommend any libraries out there that have validations for all known address formats?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to do any specific lookup, like searching by postal code or by city, I'd say to all combine the address in a single field. This way you will support the different address from different countries.

You will also support address oddities.

If you fear that the requirements are going to change, you could store the address as a Xml field. Modern database like Sql Server 2005 and 2008 can have an index on a Xml node inside a Xml column as long as you are using a schema.

It all come down to requirements. If the client need to group the data inside a grid by country, then you need a country column.

Comment: The problem here is that he may not want to sort by those specific fields currently, but what about when the requirements change in 3 months? This looks like relatively little effort now to save a LOT of head aches down the road - that's an easy win.

Comment: I think it all depends on whether you are writing user-centric code or machine-centric code. A user generally knows best how to format their own address. So really, it depends on if you're trying to give the user the best data entry experience, or if you're trying to make it easier for a computer to do sorts.

Answer (score 0):

There are no states in New Zealand, so it should definately be optional. So I think you have the right answer in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Making fields required is always a tradeoff. If the person doesn't want to fill in the info then they won't -- they'll put in a period, or garbage to get past the "required field" nanny.

I only require street_address_1 in my apps. Also, for the US and many countries, you can buy the mapping between the postal/zip code and the canonical city/state. It's not expensive. (The mapping between individual street addresses and zip is much more expensive.)
For the US, see http://www.usps.com/ncsc/addressinfo/citystate.htm

If you're including an Ajax web interface, ask for the country first, then the post code. If in the US, then use Ajax to fetch and fill in the city/state for the user from the zip.

Some non-US countries, eg UK, can have 3 lines of street addresses if you're asking people to fill in their "preferred address" Eg:

```
Mirassou          (You can register a building's name with the post office
High Street        as an alternative to its street number)
Old Town
City, Bucks postal_code
```

Larry

Answer (score 0):

Actually, city isn't even required in the US.

Many people have rural addresses on state and county roads. Publication 28 at the postal service web site has details. Different companies end up using the "city" field to store other information. This also applies to military base addresses.

[Publication 28 link](http://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/welcome.htm)